How do I write this Theorem with quantifiers?
Here is the theorem from Steven Abbot's Understanding Analysis.

Theorem. Two real numbers $a$ and $b$ are equal if and only if for every real number $\epsilon > 0$ it follows that $|a - b| < \epsilon$.

I have a two part question.

How do I write the theorem using quantifiers?

How is contradiction being used with the quantifiers? Can you show with the quantified statement how we are doing proof by contradiction?


Here's an image of the page:


The theorem is written with quantifiers! The phrases "for all" and "there exists" are quantifiers.

It is already written using quantifiers "for all" and "there exists" but if you want
$$\forall a,b:\,\Big(a=b\iff(\forall\varepsilon>0:\,|a-b|<\varepsilon)\Big)$$
The direction
$$\forall a,b:\,\Big(a=b\implies(\forall\varepsilon>0:\,|a-b|<\varepsilon)\Big)$$
is called trivial and the direction
$$\forall a,b:\,\Big((\forall\varepsilon>0:\,|a-b|<\varepsilon)\implies a=b\Big)$$
is done by proving that the negation
$$\exists a,b:\,\Big((\forall\varepsilon>0:\,|a-b|<\varepsilon)\ \mathrm{and}\ a\neq b\Big)$$
leads to a contradiction.
Hope this helps. :)

This does help a lot! What about a, and b? Wouldn’t they have the quantifier for all. Where would that go and how does that factor into the contradiction proof? Thank you!

Yes, $a$ and $b$ do need quantifiers. The "for all" quantifier would go right in front of them.

@Dr.J I edited my answer.

Thank you! This makes sense. I'm struggling to understand contradiction and the contrapositive with quantifiers. For example, you negated the for all quantifier for a, and b. I was thinking it would stay the same. Why do we negate it? Also would the contrapositive for the 3rd formula you provided be this: $$\forall a,b:,\Big(a \neq b\implies(\exists\varepsilon>0:,|a-b|>\varepsilon)\Big)$$

@Dr.J: Think about it: you have the statement "property $P$ holds for all $x$". Is the negation "property $P$ does not hold for all $x$ or "property $P$ does not hold for at least one $x$? For your contrapositive, it is correct other than the minor $\geq\varepsilon$ instead of $>\varepsilon$.

[...] Once you have done that, now think about what the negation of "property $P$ holds for at least one $x$" will be.

Oh, I see. The negation of "property P holds for at least one x" would be property p does not hold for all x. When I had tried using the quantifiers I initially thought it would be this: $$\forall a,b,\varepsilon:,\Big(|a-b|<\varepsilon\implies a=b\Big)$$. Why was this incorrect? I'm not sure why.

@Dr.J: Now $|a-b|<\varepsilon\implies a=b$ is checked for a fixed $\varepsilon$. That is clearly false; take $a=0$, $b=1$, $\varepsilon=2$ then $|0-1|<2\implies 0=1$ is absurd.

I see. Thank you for your response and answering all my questions. It is greatly appreciated!
